# React selected options for multiple select

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to init a multi-select list and it currently works as expected. But it doesn't output html select attribute and I'm seeing following warning in chrome console:

*Use the 'defaultValue' or 'value' props on  instead of setting 'selected' on .*

Data:

```
const MemberList = [
    {Text: "Administrator", Selected: true},
    {Text: "Power User", Selected: false},
    {Text: "User", Selected: true},
    {Text: "Guest", Selected: true},
];
```

Component:

```
<select multiple disabled className="m-t-20">
    {MemberList.map((member, index) =>
        <option key={`member-${index}`} selected={member.Selected}>{member.Text}</option>
    )}
</select>
```

How can I do it the right way because I cannot find enough documentation for React.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what are you looking for

```
const Option = (props) => { 
    return <option 
        value={props.value}
        defaultValue={props.selected}>
      {props.text}
    </option>
}

const MultipleSelectExample = () => {
    return <select multiple defaultValue={['foo1','foo2']}>
      <Option text={'foo'} value={'foo1'}/>
      <Option text={'baz'} value={'foo2'}/>
      <Option text={'zaz'} value={'foo'}/>
      <Option text={'kaz'} value={'foo'}/>
    </select>
}
```

Hope it will help you. Thanks!

Comment: So I only needed defaultValue={['foo1','foo2']} for the select, nothing else.

Comment: @HasanGürsoy right, if you use *multiple* for *select* - _defaultValue_ should be array